# Solve the Poisson Equation on a Riemannian Manifold

Tags: differential-geometry, partial-differential-equations

Imagine that I have a field that obeys to the Poisson equation. To solve the equation, in my bag of tools I only have the divergence theorem or the Fourier/Laplace transform. They usually are enough to tackle the problem and I'm happy with myself...

Let's then say that the field lives on a Riemannian Manifold other than Euclidean. Let's take for example  the 2-torus. Well for starters I can't use the divergence theorem since I can't really define a border at which the field (actually the gradient) is constant... I am then left with the Fourier transform technique. But, I only know the Fourier Transform on Euclidean geometry... Then, I started studying the way of generalizing the Fourier transform to another Riemannian Manifold. In general this is not possible but in some cases it is... But then, after much browsing, I read that even if one could define a FT on the manifold that wouldn't help me solve the problem...

After this very long introduction: Is that true? If it is: How would one solve the Poisson equation?

Comment: Related question by OP: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/56551/2451

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you to take a look on this [book](http://books.google.com.br/books?id=NcLiTzEwFbcC&pg=PA104&hl=pt-BR&source=gbs_toc_r&cad=4#v=onepage&q&f=false) in page 104. Also, you can find a lot of information on [this](http://books.google.com.br/books?id=qE2qayXk44AC&pg=PA47&hl=pt-BR&source=gbs_toc_r&cad=4#v=onepage&q&f=false) one, in particular, in the part where he treats Poincare inequality (Theorem 2.10) and Proposition 2.6.

Comment: I believe that what you're telling (showing) me is the necessary condition for a solution to exist (If I didn't read the references correctly please tell me). I've seen that in lots of places but not one has actually solved the problem on a particular manifold...For example on a cylinder with a point source it shouldn't be too difficult (although I can't solve it =/)...

That's what I asking. A way of solving the equation.

Comment: Dear @PML, please take a look in page 104 of Aubin, in particular, take a look in item $\gamma$ after $\beta$. There he solves the equation by using the classical variational setting, i.e. a) define the energy funcional; b) show this functional is bounded below and take a minimizing sequence; c) show this sequence converges.

Comment: Oh I see. I'm sorry, I, clearly, didn't look thoroughly enough the references that you indicated. I'll take a look again. Thank you for you help.